# How to download latest files from s3 bucket into local machine using Airflow

Tags: airflow

Is there a way to download latest files from S3 bucket into my local system using Airflow .

Since I am a newbie to Airflow I don't have much idea on how to proceed. Please assist.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: You could use [`S3KeySensor`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/sensors/s3_key/index.html#airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.s3_key.S3KeySensor) to detect when a certain key appears in an S3 bucket and then use [`S3Hook.read_key()`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/s3/index.html#airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3.S3Hook.read_key) to get the content of the key.

Assuming you are completely new to Airflow, I would suggest:

- Start with [the tutorial](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial.html)
- Read up on [Connections, Hooks](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/connections.html#connections-hooks), and [Sensors](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/sensors.html#sensors)
- Use [this example](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/example_dags/example_s3_bucket.py) as a starting point for your own DAG

As a followup:

- Browse [the amazon provider package docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/index.html) to see what else there is for working with AWS services
- Look through [other examples](https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/master/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/example_dags)